# Best Practices for Incremental Seeds with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, continuous-integration, capistrano, continuous-deployment

RoR 3.2.13 and 3.0.1 capistrano

My application requires initial data via *rake db:seed*. My continuous integration server does automatic deployment each time someone join a new feature and all test pass. Among the latest task is *rake db:seed*.

The first time works fine, but in the following fail the seeds because some records already exist in database.

Which strategy suggest me to run the seeds incrementally.

**Note that:**

- The seeds may vary over time.
- The application already contains data on production.
- Should be run automatically from the Continuous Integration server.

Who should have the responsibility not to repeat information: Capistrano, the seed itself, the application, continuous integration server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way for seeds is seed-fu. With [seed-fu](https://github.com/mbleigh/seed-fu) we can make idempotents seeds and means you can run sometimes without alter final result. the way for different seeds by environment or deploys is [seedbank](https://github.com/james2m/seedbank)

Answer (score 0):

In our team we are using migrations for change db schema and also existing data.

Comment: then how do you do if have differents deployments with differents seeds?